# VBA loop only going through one sheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, spreadsheet

I made a function which returns the total sum of values in a specific range from all sheets in the workbook and multiply it with a scalar. The For loop is meant to go until the last sheet in the book via the sheet Count property, but I reduced it to 2 sheets to help me figure out what was going wrong.

As it stands, the For loop exits after one iteration and I can't figure out why that is from looking at the code. The Do loop is resolving as it should.Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Public Function FPP_Total()

Dim Book As Workbook: Set Book = ActiveWorkbook
Dim sheetCount As Integer: sheetCount = Book.Sheets.Count
Dim total As Long
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet

rowCount = 2

For i = 3 To 5

    Set currentSheet = Book.Sheets(i)

    Do

    total= (total+ currentSheet.Cells(rowCount, 3).Value)
    rowCount = rowCount + 1

    Loop Until IsEmpty(currentSheet.Cells(rowCount, 1).Value)

Next

FPP_Total = total * 5
```

End Function

Comment: Have you stepped through your code? It could be looping through each sheet but just not summing the way you think it should be.

Comment: Seems like you do not need your `Do` loop. Just use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum([range])`

Comment: @urdearboy I would, but the ranges may differ from one sheet to the next as items(rows) are added or removed. The Do loop is there to allow for that flexibility, as the data is sectioned off into blocks with at least one blank row/collumn dividing them.

Comment: You can create a dynamic range still

Comment: Also, rowCount keeps iterating every time you go to a new sheet so it skips ahead each time. Try putting the rowCount = 2 inside the For loop

Comment: @TheJeebo Doh. Thanks for pointing it out. Visual Studio really spoiled me, I need to get better at catching these kinds of mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to sum each sheet from `C2` down to the last row in the column.

Instead of creating a nested loop (*which @TheJeebo identified as the source of your problem*), you can simply identify the dynamic range in question and sum this range all at once like below. Nest this inside a sheet loop to achieve desired result

---

```
Public Function FPP_Total()

Dim ws As Worksheet         'Worksheet
Dim lr As Long              'Last Row
Dim total As Long
Dim i as Long

For i = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    lr = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    total = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("C2:C" & lr))
Next i

FPP_Total = total * 5

End Function
```

Comment: I understand the dynamic range option, but how does it behave when a blank row(or few) separates two sets of rows in a column that represent different data. 

In my particular case for example, the top row of the sheet is column names/titles up until the 41st row, then come two blank rows and then another row of column titles under which are further numerical values. Like two tables one under the other.

How would that dynamic range behave for that case? Would it stop on that blank row as I need it to or would it take all the values in that column into account?

Comment: These are statements that you can test yourself FYI (just run it and find out). If you did do that, in the current state you should notice this will go alllll the way down to the last used row. I am going to the very bottom of column and essentially using `CTRL SHIFT UP` to find last cell. Instead, it sounds like you want to use `CTRL SHIFT DOWN` from the top. So.... try `lr = ws.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row`